# El Captian not showing user account after creating second one

Tags: mac, macos, password, user-account

I am using Macbook Pro with El-Captian. I had only one user account in the machine and I created one another. After creating the new one, old user account is not showing in the login screen. It is showing in the Users & Group listing and I have tried a number of things like checking Firevault, creating root user etc. Actually my work files are there in the old account and even I can access the files with root access some of the applications like Vagrant is not working fine. It will be helpful if anyone can suggest me what I need to do now to get access to the old user account. I tried to change login option to Name and Password, but it also not working.

Comment: Does it show in Fast User Switching? https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/os-x-yosemite/9781491948484/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages2170769.png.jpg

Comment: No. It is not showing there also.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have Automatic login turned on. Try to turn it off from the same window where you set login option to name and password.

Comment: No. I checked it and it is Off